# TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len() for Sentimental Analysis

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, sentiment-analysis

Trying some Sentimental Analysis on some csv files and keep getting an error I'm not sure how to fix

I tried changing in the loop type.

```
readFeedback = pandas.read_csv("Feedback.csv", header=0, escapechar="\\", 
                    index_col="nps_score", error_bad_lines=False)

cleanedAnswers = []

for i in range(0, len(readFeedback["question_22"])) :
    cleanedAnswers.append(" ".join( KaggleWord2VecUtility.review_to_wordlist(readFeedback["question_22"][i], True)))
```

I expended it to clean the questions of stop words but it gave me the error:

> TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len() for Sentimental Analysis

Comment: `readFeedback["question_22"]` appears to be a float? you need an iterable to use `len()`

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(0, len(readFeedback["question_22"])) :
```

Here you have `len(readFeedback["question_22"]):`, This isn't any list that can be iterated through. It's a float.

Change it to an iterable and it'll work right.

Comment: How do I do that? I tried: answerList = list(readFeedback["question_22"])

 for i in range(0, len(answerList)): This gave me the same result

Comment: It didn't need range, it loops through recursively with just for i in readFeedback["question_22"]. Thank you fir your help